# Parse - Can I send a push notification to a device that has one app but not another?

Tags: push-notification, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications

Here's the scenario: I'm just getting started with Parse.com. I have apps that come in pairs, Lite and Full. I want to occasionally let users of the Lite apps know if the Full app has been marked down. However, if possible, I'd like to avoid sending such messages to people who already have the Full app installed, even if they still have the Lite app on their device.

From a data perspective, I think I could send `[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor]` up to Parse as additional data when I register for remote notifications. If I could query all my data (from both apps) in one giant bucket, I could then filter out devices where the same identityForVendor value was associated with both apps. (In SQL-speak, I would left join my Full app data on the identifierForVendor and exclude rows with non-null values on the joined side.)

However, when I go to the Parse push message console, it appears that Push messages are always sent inside the context of a given app -- so you're in a silo from which you can't see or filter by data from your other apps.

Is this just a limitation of the Parse web console? I'm still getting my arms around the API, so maybe I can do it there? Or is this a limitation of Parse itself?

EDIT: I see that I misunderstood the Parse concept of an "app." It doesn't necessarily refer to only one literal app, but it seems to be a logical grouping of apps that all fit under the same umbrella. I was able to get my Full and Lite test apps both receiving notifications while grouped inside the same logical app, and I associated identifierForVendor data with the Installation object. But I don't see a way to do the "left join"-esque query that I describe above. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to do something similar (send pushes between two applications). 
First, a question: to your two apps logically grouped as you say, how did you do it ... did you use the same parse applicationID and clientKey in both apps?

Second, a potential answer for your question of how you could send pushes only to distinct groups. Here's what I would do:

To send pushes only to people who have the Lite version installed, make sure that when Lite registers for push on Parse, that it sets its **channel** as Lite. Then use Cloud code or the web console to only send pushes to channel=Lite

To send pushes only to a specific installation or set of installations, make sure that you save a column on the PFInstallation object that allows you to identify Lite versus Full. Then, use Cloud Code to retrieve all PFInstallation objects that have what you want set (you can even filter down to specific PFInstallation attributes), and send these PFInstallations to Parse push. This should work because (see API reference for PFPush on cloud code / javascript), Push takes as its identifier a set of PFInstallation.